# Update data on server using http-client Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have problem with update method on my server.
I have `DataStorageServiceService` server where I have method for update:

```
storeProduct(category: CategoryModel):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(this.cateogryUrl, category, httpOptions).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError<CategoryModel>('addHero'))

    )
  }
```

I have component `AdminComponent` where I have array `categoryList` with my data from server. I have method `storeProduct`:

```
storeProduct() {
    let index = 0;

    // this.categoryList[0].products.push(new ProductModel(1, '2', '2', 2, '3'))
    for (let category of this.categoryList) {
      index++;
      if (category.name == this.productForm.value.category) {
        this.product.name = this.productForm.value.name;
        this.product.image = this.productForm.value.image;
        this.product.description = this.productForm.value.description;


        this.categoryList[0].products.push(this.product)
      }
    }
    this.dataStorageServiceService.storeProduct(this.categoryList[0]);

  }
```

I make changes in `categoryList` array but this is not send on my server.

Comment: You don't subscribe to the observable returned by storeProduct(), so nothing is ever sent.

Comment: Thanks I solved this.